# Conditional If and ENUM AWS CDK (Python)

Tags: python, conditional-statements, aws-cdk

I just use CDK v2 for template generation. When I try to recreate Conditions with Enums I get an error.

> Expected enum value, got
> {"$jsii.byref":"aws-cdk-lib.Intrinsic@10012"}

Example code:

```
    param_enableDeletionProtection = CfnParameter(self, "EnableDeletionProtection", 
        type="String",
        allowed_values=['True','False'],
        description="Whether critical services (like RDS) get provisioned with deletion protection or not")
condition_enable_deletion_protection = CfnCondition(self, "DeletionProtectionEnabled",
            expression=Fn.condition_equals(param_enableDeletionProtection.value_as_string, 'True')
    )
    cond_removal_policy=Fn.condition_if(condition_enable_deletion_protection.logical_id,
        RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
        RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
    )
    s3_Bucket = s3.Bucket(self, "MyBucket",
        bucket_name="my-bucket-name",
        removal_policy=cond_removal_policy
    )
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fn.condition_if` is for digging into the guts of the cloudformation template, and will return a statement - not the RETAIN or DESTROY enum that this property is expecting. As you are using python, you can litterally just do this:

```
   cond_removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN if some_condition_true else RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
```

This does mean that the condition needs to be set *during synth* which takes place before  deployment. However, it seems you are already using parameter store for other things, you can continue to make use of that here and either use context variables (`cdk deploy Stack\* -c a_variable_name=someValue`) or other methods to determine what this should be at deployment time.

remember, CDK doesn't actually do anything with deployment. It ONLY synthesizes a CloudFormation template, then passes template off to cloudformation to deploy. So your code is never in effect during the deployment, only in creating the infrastructure.  Anything you need to happen *during* the deployment should be handled either by a custom resource lambda or better yet a Pipeline. Anything after has to be a custom resource. Anything that can occur before beginning deployment can be handled inside CDK stacks (such as discovering information to set up the properties of given resources)

Comment: I dont want compile time variables, I want runtime CF Parameters. While I get that CDK v2 has added a lot of built-in pipeline stuff, I am not using any of that. I am merely reproducing CloudFormaton code (with a default stack synthesizer).
In CloudFormation it is valid to, create a Parameter and Condition and then use syntax:
`Fn::If: [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]` on any attribute
i.e.
`
    myS3Bucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        DeletionPolicy: Fn::If: [EnableDeletionProtection, "Retain", "Delete"]
`
This should be possible in CDK to reproduce.

Comment: then you can't use the L2 Constructs of s3 buckets which expect the enum values. Instead you have to use the L1 constructs of `cfnBucket`  - of course, doing so you loose all the hooks that make CDK nice. -- you might also be able to get away with doing it via interacting with `scope.node` and manually manipulate those various parts. That is pretty much your only option, as the L2 constructs really are designed not to do such things so they can take advantage of all the QoL hooks

Comment: That makes sense, use lower lever constructs which don't enforce strong typing. Thanks